# How to dired-find-file for ONLY directories in Dired?

Tags: dired

I want to add keybinding to Dired mode for entering directory, and ONLY directory. By default enter key is bound to function `dired-find-file`. The problem with it is that its or opening new dired buffer if it is directory under cursor, or open file for editing if its file.

So I added two shortcuts for going to parent directory and stepping in directory under cursor this way:

`(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<left>") 'dired-jump)
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<right>") 'dired-find-file)`

As you may guess the problem is in last - `dired-find-file` will work on non-directories too, and I want it not to do anything. So my question - is there a specific function for stepping in directory under cursor or, if not - is there a way to check if there is directory under cursor in dired mode to construct my own function? Thx.

Comment: Do you really want each directory in a different buffer?  I use the `dired` `i` command, which gives an error if it's not a directory and expands it in the current buffer if it is.  If that's not what you wanted, looking at the source for it might be a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an easy one to write:

```el
(defun dired-find-directory ()
  "A `dired-find-file' which only works on directories."
  (interactive)
  (let ((find-file-run-dired t)
        (file (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
    (when (file-directory-p file)
      (find-file file))))
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot!